# How to filter array data using Jquery Date?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, filter

in my view page I'm display this array in a `<div>` in this view page again i want filter this array like below

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:20 [▶]
  1 => array:20 [▶]
  2 => array:20 [▶]
  3 => array:20 [▶]
  4 => array:21 [▶]
]
```

in that array i have **date** key like

```
 "date" => "2016-4-20 03:30:00"
 "date" => "2017-6-20 03:30:00"
 "date" => "2025-8-20 03:30:00"
 "date" => "2030-12-20 03:30:00"
 "date" => "2016-8-20 03:30:00"
```

im using jquery to filter this array if i select 2017-1-01 i want show only two out of five how can i at the movement im here

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Your dates appear to be in PHP an you want to filter via jQuery? That might be more effort than it's worth. Why not filter the php first?

Comment: @Rasclatt im already displayed this array in my view using autocomplete now in this view page i want filter this array by date

Comment: @Rasclatt you there ?

Comment: Did you try the answer below (except without the syntax error)?

Comment: yes i tried but it wont work

Comment: Well it's the right idea, if it didn't have a syntax error, it probably would work. His answer is create a storage array first `var result = [];` then loop through the array of dates you have, convert the dates so you can compare them `var date = Date.parse(e.date);` and `if (value.date > date)....etc`

Comment: The final output of the array would actually be stored in the `result` array.

Comment: `$( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

        }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
            var date = Date.parse(e.date);
            
            alert(date);
            
        });
      } );` i treid this but i didnt get alert  why ?

Comment: Well, I haven't used this particular library so I can not really say specifically, but I don't know where `'dp.change'` is coming from or if this syntax is what is supposed to be there `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ }).on....`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you for search by date:

```
<script>
$( function() {  
    var result = [];  
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var date = Date.parse(e.date);                                          
        if (!!date) {
            $.each( yourarray, function( value, key ) {
                if (value.date > date) {
                    result.push(value);
                }
            });
        }               
    });                                   
})
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have a syntax error...this line you may be missing the front part?? `}).on('dp.change', function (e) {`

Comment: @rvchauhan whre to get  this **db.chnage**

Comment: dp.change is your datepicker change inbuilt function...so you can set your datepicker change function.

Comment: how to pass this `var date` into same view php file ?